# Python: How is it possible for two strings with the same value to not be the same?

Tags: python

I have the following string: 'google.com'

I am reading the string from a file:

```
with open("ip_hostnames.txt", "r") as file_hosts:
    "Reading IPs..."
    for line in file_hosts:
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        split_line = line.split(',')
        hostname = split_line[0]
        ip = split_line[1]
        # output_lines.append(get_ssl_cert(hostname))
        output_lines.append(run_cert(hostname.strip(' \t\n\r'), ip.strip(' \t\n\r')))
```

And calling a function:

```
def run_cert(hostname, ip):
    host = 'google.com'
    cert = CertInfo(host=hostname, port=443)  # ('RC4-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 128)
    info = cert.cipher()
```

I a getting errors because the servername google is not valid in the following (read from file):

```
google.com, 74.125.196.101
google.com, 74.125.196.138
```

I have done some digging, and replacing `hostname` with `host` resolve the issue, but they are literally exactly the same string. There is absolutely no difference to the human eye with these strings, but for some reason, python says they are false:

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: What is their `repr`?

Comment: `{AttributeError}'str' object has no attribute 'repr'` when i try to find out on hostname

Comment: `repr` is a function. You apply it to the strings: `print(repr(host))` / `print(repr(hostname)))`

Comment: I actually just resolved it by copying and pasting the text in sublime and resaving it. Not sure what changed, but it seems to now hold true that host == hostname